# Verilog mux select condition not correctly evaluated

Tags: verilog

I have a Verilog question. For the following wire `test`, somehow the mux select condition `B + 1'b1 == C` does not evaluate to true when B = 51, C = 52.

I feel like I'm missing something about how this is being interpreted from the tool's perspective. Does anyone know why this is?

```
wire [4:0] A, D;
wire [31:0] B;
wire [32:0] C;

wire test = A <  (B + 1'b1 == C) ? D : 0;
```

Comment: Your full condition is not `B + 1'b1 == C` but `A <  (B + 1'b1 == C)`. The `?:` operator has a lowest precedence in Verilog

Comment: It's always a good practice to make good use of parenthesis to avoid the headache of keeping in mind the precedence.

Comment: agreed XD, it's really painful especially with nested muxes. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Table 11-2—Operator precedence and associativity* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) defines the order of operator precedence. From that table, the order of your operators is

1. + (binary)
2. == (equality)
3. < (relational)
4. ?: (conditional)
5. = (assignment)

To get what your intended, you would have to write

```
wire test = A < (B + 1'b1 == C ? D : 0) ;
```

I would also add an extra set of parenthesis around the self-determined select expression

```
wire test = A < ( (B + 1'b1 == C) ? D : 0) ;
```